# Set initial focus in an Android application

Tags: android, focus

In my Android application it automatically focuses the first `Button` I have in my layout, giving it an orange outline. How can I set the initial focus preferably in XML, and can this be set to nothing?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You could use the `requestFocus` tag:

```
<Button ...>
  <requestFocus />
</Button>
```

I find it odd though that it auto-focuses one of your buttons, I haven't observed that behavior in any of my views.

Comment: Yeah, it has happened with two of my applications now. I guess I could requestFocus onto a element that doesn't change like a TextView or would this not be allowed?

Comment: @stealthcopter: can you tell me which Android version you're using. I'm using 2.1 & 2.2, but requestFocus doesn't work.

Comment: Well I've been using it across all versions, but the problem I was having seemed to disappear on it's own so I haven't investigated much.

Comment: I've tried the XML approach, I've tried the programmatic approach. Yet the EditText retains focus. VERY ANNOYING !

Comment: for an EditText, use programmatic method and be sure to use `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`

Comment: <requestFocus /> is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#requestfocus-element

Comment: I have found it when I added a new TextView however this is not seen in xml while typing ctrl +space.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere, see [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 68):

@Someone Somewhere, I tried all of the above to no avail. The fix I found is from http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/remove-autofocus-edittext-android . Basically, you need to create an invisible layout just above the problematic Button:

```
<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
              android:layout_width="0px"
              android:layout_height="0px" >
    <requestFocus />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I was able to gain focus on an AlertDialog and enabling focusableintouchmode helped me get it right. Essentially, here's how: alert.show(); alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).requestFocus();

Comment: Thank you! This was the **only** solution that worked in my case. Although I used it slightly different; I put the focus stuff in a `RelativeLayout` containing the `EditText`.

Comment: With Android P following changes are coming to the platform:
"Views with 0 area (either a width or a height is 0) are no longer focusable.
Additionally, activities no longer implicitly assign initial focus in touch-mode. Instead, it is up to you to explicitly request initial focus, if desired."

Answer (score 29):

Set both `:focusable` and `:focusableInTouchMode` to true and call `requestFocus`. It does the trick.

Comment: Yes this is the true solution to fix it. Thanks Anders

Answer (score 25):

I found this worked best for me.

In AndroidManifest.xml `<activity> element` add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

This always hides the keyboard when entering the activity.

Comment: Easy and clean!

Comment: great... this is very impressive!

Answer (score 11):

I just add this line of code into `onCreate()`:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

Use the code below,

```
TableRow _tableRow =(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRowMainBody);
tableRow.requestFocus();
```

that should work.

Answer (score 4):

@Someone Somewhere I used this to clear focus:

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

and it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
android:focusedByDefault="true"
```

Comment: Attribute `focusedByDefault` is only used in API level 26 and higher (current min is 21).