# Don't let button focus initially in touch mode

Tags: android

I have a layout in which the first button keeps grabbing focus as soon as the activity is started (if in touch mode). Is there a way to politely ask the activity to not auto-focus? I know I can put in a focusable dummy layout with 0 width/height to do this, seems like there should be something better.

Reference: [Set initial focus in an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743559/set-initial-focus-in-an-android-application)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too.  I got around it by setting the focusable and focusableInTouchMode attributes to true in the parent LinearLayout.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Yeah that works, but I mean what we really want is something like an activity flag, asking not to auto-focus the first item. I don't think something like that exists in android though?

Comment: I don't know if that exists or not.  Is there a particular reason you don't want anything to have focus?

Comment: Yeah, it just looks a bit silly to have a control initially focused when landing on a new activity.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was vague:  I agree that it looks silly for a button to have focus automatically.  I don't mind the parent view having focus though, because it is not visible to the user.