# EditText request focus

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am designing a login page as:

```
UserName:  .....

Password:  .....

     LoginButton
```

When the activity starts, I want the focus to go to "UserName" textbox and the keyboard to appear.

**I am using the following code:**

```
    boolean checkFocus=user.requestFocus();
    Log.i("CheckFocus", ""+checkFocus);
    if(checkFocus==true)
    {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(user, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
```

I don't understand where to write this code to make the keyboard appear when the activity starts and focus is on the "UserName" editText box. Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Programatically:

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Through xml:

```
<EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Or call onClick method manually.

Comment: no in Layout XML where you declare edit text..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743559/set-initial-focus-in-an-android-application

Comment: you are testing on which device??
sometime Android O/S doesn't open keyboard even after on focus while activity start. This often happens in small screen devices..

Actually o/s intelligently detects the screen size and decides whether to show keyboard or not..

Another thing you can try is to call onclick listner of your edit text box manually...like : editText.onClick(null); and also make a check in onClick listner to handle null event (i.e prevent application from being crashed..)

Comment: I am testing it on HTC desire.

Comment: no still that was not working..U tell me one thing that when my activity starts ,then  first it would create xml file and using setcontentView(),

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4873/discussion-between-awais-tariq-and-kanika)

Comment: and only after this statement ,I am setting user.requestfocus()...then why its not showing me the QWERTY keypad?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, I got the answer.. just simply edit the `manifest` file as:

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

and set `EditText.requestFocus()` in `onCreate()`..

Thanks..

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead, this is the only thing that worked for me! thanks mate

Answer (score 6):

`youredittext.requestFocus()` call it from activity

```
oncreate();
```

and use the above code there

Comment: user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Comment: I did..but it was not working..I already appended my code after these lines

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668210/automatic-popping-up-keyboard-on-start-activity

Answer (score 1):

having the soft keyboard disabled (only external keyboards enabled), I fixed it by moving the cursors at the end on the EditText:

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
    editTextUserName.setError("Please enter username");
    editTextUserName.requestFocus();
    return;
}

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
    editTextPassword.setError("Enter a password");
    editTextPassword.requestFocus();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set to the Activity in Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Set focus, when a view is ready:

```
fun setFocus(view: View, showKeyboard: Boolean = true){
    view.post {
        if (view.requestFocus() && showKeyboard)
            activity?.openKeyboard() // call extension function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but only solution is working for me is

```
edittext.requestFocus()   
edittext.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,0f,0f,0))    
edittext.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,0f,0f,0))
```

I used this to open keyboard programatically.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly in 2023.

add below line in manifest file for the activity you want the keyboard to open.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

And in activity/Fragment add

```
 if (editText.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            editText.requestFocus()
        }
```

If you do'nt add this if clause keyboard will open in activity resume state as well.