# How do I position the cursor at a default position?

Tags: java, android, position, cursor

The image shows the screenshot of my application. As you can see that the cursor is at the text field pertaining to "Height". Whenever I launch my app the default cursor position is at "Height". I want it to be on "Mass".
How do I do it ? I can't figure out. Please help.!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try putting this in your onCreate: massEditText.requestFocus();
(You'll need to change the edittext name to whatever yours is called)

Comment: possible duplicate of [EditText request focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077755/edittext-request-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your **.xml file**:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>
```

And set the `<requestFocus />` tag appropriately.
Also, you can call:

```
EditText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either update your .xml file as follows.

```
<EditText 
 android:id=@+id/etMass
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus/> </EditText>
```

Or Use Code:

```
EditText etMass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMass);
etMass.requestFocus();
```