# Is there a way to cancel the next field being focused on Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Basically, I am validating a field when the the field loses focus. When an error occurs when we check at the OnFocusChangeListener, I want it to cancel the focus and stay on the same field. Is there a way to cancel the focus on it?

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
{
        if (!hasFocus)
        {
            if(checkError(v))
            {
               // Cancel focus here
            }
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think requestFocus() should do the trick, see this answer for usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077842/1173391

**Update:**
I think you are missing the check for the view id, because the *onFocusChange* method is implemented via interface in your class:

try setting this:

> if (v.getId() == myEditText.id)

as first check on the focus change method; you have to do it for every edit-field (or use a switch instead of if) .... 
OR

attach an OnFocusChangeListener to every single field:

```
edittext1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    }
});
```

Comment: did that but keyboard still has focus on the next field. It seems it has multiple focus, since now there are 2 edittext that have a blinking cursors.

Comment: do you have a unique id on the field you are trying to focus?

Comment: yup, i even save some of the reference for each field.