# Soft Keyboard doesn't appear when tapping on EditText

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, android-edittext

I got a really weird problem. I am working on an Android app. If I use my layout on an Activity everything works as expected. But, if I use my layout in a Fragment the Soft Keyboard doesn't show anymore when I focus an `EditText`.

Here is the code of my fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import mariohenkel.com.familycheck.R;
import mariohenkel.com.familycheck.fragment.api.BaseFragment;

/**
 * Created by Developer on 15.06.2015.
 */
public class SuchenFragment  extends BaseFragment {

    public static SuchenFragment newInstance() {
        return new SuchenFragment();
    }

    private View v;
    EditText etOrt;

    public SuchenFragment(){ }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("SuchenFragment", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_suchen_neu, container, false);

        loadViewComponents();
        loadInfoView();

        return v;
    }

    private void loadViewComponents() {
        etOrt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText_Ort);

        etOrt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("onClick", "onClick");

            }
        });
    }

    private void loadInfoView() {

    }
}
```

The `onClick()` Event of the EditText fires correctly. I tried to force show the keyboard within the `onClick()` with following code

```
InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) 
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
mImm.showSoftInput(SearchEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

but without success. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I am using this project https://github.com/halysongoncalves/Material-Design-Example and I am trying to use the second tab. The first one is working as expected.

EDIT2: This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:minHeight="60dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titel_ort"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Ort: "/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Ort eingeben"
                android:id="@+id/editText_Ort"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:background="@color/gruen"
            android:minHeight="60dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titel_kategorie"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Kategorie: "/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner_Kategorie"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:background="@color/gelb"
            android:minHeight="60dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titel_suchbegriff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Suchbegriff: "/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText_Suchbegriff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Suchbegriff"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tl_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/theme_dialer_primary"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titel_suchen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Jetzt suchen"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Update: One more weird thing. If I open another activity and go back to the activity which hosts the fragments the keyboard is working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

In your xml use, in your `EditText` tags

```
<requestFocus />
```

source : [EditText request focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077755/edittext-request-focus)

Also checkout : [Android: show soft keyboard automatically when focus is on an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403632/android-show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-focus-is-on-an-edittext?rq=1)

*P.S. Little exploration on SO or Google would have the problem, and will save your time of writing the question.*

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I added the <requestFocus /> to the appropriate EditText but still no luck.

Comment: What is your AndroidManifest declaration for this activity?

Comment: <activity
            android:name="mariohenkel.com.familycheck.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: does the emulator has show soft input enabled? also add your layout!

Comment: I am debugging on a real device (Galaxy Nexus). I added my layout to the original post

Comment: try giving an inputType to the EditText

Comment: Still no luck after adding input type

Answer (score 0):

After recreating my project step by step I found my mistake.

In my first fragment I used an AsyncTask with .get() to aquire a SID from a server. After I removed that .get() and changed my following logic everything worked as expected.