# EditText is not working in CardView

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-cardview

I'm trying to put an EditText or AppCompatEditText in a CardView but EditText is not getting focus. Unable to find what I'm missing in the layout.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_secondary_ultra_light">
            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:drawableTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077755/edittext-request-focus) is not working in my case.

Comment: Put a container layout inside CardView lets say RelativeLayout. inside that put Edittext/AppCompatEditText and try

Comment: @Raghavendra same condition :(

Comment: No @Sayem.. It's not duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` property in **CardView** and now it is working properly.

Thanks for everybody's efforts.

Answer (score 2):

dont use **AppCompatEditText** use **EditText** instead 
it will use AppCompatEditText by default

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_secondary_ultra_light">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                android:drawableTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you can check in the **AppCompatEditText** documentation that EditText uses it by default.

> This will automatically be used when you use EditText in your layouts.
>   You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom
>   views.

Answer (score 0):

Use Edit text instead of AppCompatEditText.

Comment: u can use something like that:

Answer (score 0):

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    >
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: use Edit text inside Linear layout @khan

Answer (score 0):

Though the solutions here should have worked, you can use a hack to save time.
In your code:

```
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId); 
        et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                    ((EditText) view).requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
                                       getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
             }
        });
```

But before using this, please make sure that your EditText is not being overlapped by some other views. That might be the issue which doesn't need this workaround.

Comment: Well try @Prasad, But key board is not being opened by the android. Only cursor is blinking.

Comment: Check the new changes.