# Not able to focus on the last EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a ScrollView which cointains a Linear Layout,
When I create and add a EditText programatically to the layout my code is supposed to scroll to the bottom, but then the focus goes to the second from bottom field instead of what I want which is for it to focus the bottom field and I can't work out why.

Here is the code:

```
public void addPlayer(View view){
    ScrollView scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerAddScroll);
    EditText tv = new EditText(this);
    tv.setHint("Player " + (playerCount + 1));
    playerCount++;
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    LinearLayout playerListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playerListView);
    playerListView.addView(tv);
    playerFields.add(tv);
    scrollview.post(scrollBottom);
}
```

This is what scrollBottom does

```
Runnable scrollBottom=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerAddScroll);
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
};
```

My code causes this (Not focusing last field):

[image]

Comment: `tv.requestFocus()` -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077755/edittext-request-focus

Comment: @Pavlus i tried that after
scrollview.fullScroll() but it did nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code like this and it will work fine !

```
    Runnable scrollBottom = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        //This linear is the linearLayout which you added your textView to it 
        LinearLayout playerListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        playerListView.getChildAt(playerListView.getChildCount()-1).requestFocus();

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix by adding `android:paddingBottom="5dp"` to my LinearLayout in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to dynamically request focus for the last EditText after fullScroll method. the code is in the Runnable scrollBottom

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(linearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        editText.requestFocus();
```