# Why my focus is on cancel button

Tags: android, button, dialog, android-edittext, focus

I have a password input `dialog` in the Android `fragment`. When using the soft keyboard, if a password is wrong a dialog will still show and focus will stay in the `editText` input box.

The problem is, when a user uses physical keyboards and the password is not right, the focus will be on the cancel button (I have two `buttons` in the `dialog`, cancel is on the left and OK is on the right). How can I set the focus on the `editText`? I've tried to use the `requestFocus()` function, but it does not work.

Comment: try `editText.requestFocus()`

Comment: see my edit content, sorry it does not work

Comment: I add it in another place  it worked but the cancel button still shown selected status for a very short time, I have no idea that how can I find the default focus set, it looks like it focus on the cancel button first and then focus on the edittext.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743559/set-initial-focus-in-an-android-application