# Give initial accessibility focus to a view in fragment in the layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, accessibility

I have a fragment in an activity. When the activity adds the fragment, I want to give initial accessibility focus to a view within that fragment through xml. I can do it via code, but my senior dev doesn't like it.

I tried setting `:focusable` and `:focusableInTouchMode` to true and `<requestFocus/>` but it doesn't work.

When the activity launches and adds the fragment, nothing is focused for accessibility so `:accessibilityTraversalBefore` doesn't work either.

I read this post: [Set initial focus in an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743559/set-initial-focus-in-an-android-application), but the solution for this doesn't work for me. Maybe because the view is in a fragment which is added dynamically.

Comment: What was the soluton with code? So we may translate it to xml

Comment: Adding observers to ViewTreeObserver of the View. When the view becomes visible, the listeners gets triggered and sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) does the trick