# Android: Force EditText to remove focus?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I would like to be able to remove the focus from the EditText. For example if the Keyboard appears, and the user hides it with the back button, I would like the focus and the cursor to disappear. How can it be done?

Comment: Is there any other view that can be focused after EditText?

Comment: Is it possible to focus a WebView?

Comment: See my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890033/how-to-remove-focus-from-single-edittext/12530226#12530226

Comment: check dis out..
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: one line code  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46580242/6611895

Comment: for removing the cursor from edit text editText.setCursorVisible(false);

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can add this to `onCreate` and it will hide the keyboard every time the `Activity` starts.

You can also programmatically change the focus to another item.

```
 this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Works on M Preview. Thank you

Comment: how do you do this on a DialogFragment?

Comment: @Mr.Noob If you have a text field inside your DialogFragment, exactly the same.

Comment: To guys like me who first skipped the comments under the question itself : @AmritpalSingh has a more elegant way (using only XML attributes) to achieve this. Check it out !

Comment: to re-gain the focus, use `this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);` and `editText.requestFocus();`

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="true" for parent layout

Comment: beware, this requires an a window container, doesn't work inside a custom view

Answer (score 451):

You can make cursor and focus disappear by

```
edittext.clearFocus();
```

But detect when the key board hide is a hard work.

Comment: clearFocus() does not work.

Comment: It works, but it sets the focus back to the first focusable view in the activity, so if you have only one view in the activity you may think it doesn't, but it does work, you have to understand its behavior :)

Comment: How do I go about returning the focus to the EditText? I've tried using .requestFocus(); but this doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a few apps, in those where I'm using a fragment, clearFocus() works, in those where I just have 1 activity it doesn't work, the focus just jumps to the first editText.

Comment: If anyone else is struggling to get this to work, if you add `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the root `Layout` of your activity or fragment, this changes the focus to the `Layout` instead of the `EditText`.

Comment: this works. but i had to manully hide the keyboard as well

Answer (score 191):

Add `LinearLayout` before `EditText` in your XML.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px" />
```

Or you can do this same thing by adding these lines to view before your 'EditText'.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Quick Search"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: I liked this solution used in combination with a .clearFocus() on my EditText (which was the first focusable item in the layout, so clearFocus() didn't work on its own). Spoofing the LinearLayout to be focusable is a simple and easy solution. Nice work Singh Arjun :)

Comment: You'll only need to use `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` because setting this to true will also ensure that this view is focusable.

Comment: only add **android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**

Comment: I don't know why but for this work I should use android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"

Answer (score 110):

## Remove focus but remain focusable:

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setFocusable(true);
```

EditText will lose focus, but can gain it again on a new touch event.

Comment: This seems to shift the focus to the next focusable view, rather than removing the focus from the edit text.

It seems like Android doesn't ever want to be "unfocused"; I opted to make the root layout focusable / focusableInTouchMode in my project for this reason. 

It makes semantic sense as well: when you don't want to be focusing on the particular edit text, setting the focus to the root layout is akin to taking a step back and focusing on the full activity / fragment instead of the particular view.

Comment: Thanks for a simple trick!!! Worked perfectly

Comment: Only solution that works for me

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Comment: You can try ``clearFocus``

Comment: If you do this inside the EditText's onFocusChangeListener, on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) it will yield a stack overflow (crash).

Answer (score 79):

Add these two properties to your parent layout (ex: Linear Layout, Relative Layout)

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

It will do the trick :)

Comment: Best solution, works without adding new View. Thanks

Comment: What is the underlying logic behind this

Comment: Dont wonder. Android sometimes does wonders that it's own creators dont understand.

Comment: Should be on top.

Comment: @UtsavGupta the underlying (and unpredictable) logic/behavior is that when the focus is lost from a view, android will set it to the “first” view that supports it, in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Very Simple solution, you earned my vote up

Comment: this one worked. thanks

Comment: So simple, so good. Keyboard is hidden and all the views work as expected when clicking into them. Thank you.

Answer (score 78):

[remove autofocus edittext android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/remove-autofocus-edittext-android)

It's working for me

**Edit** In the link they suggest to use LinearLayout, but simple View will work

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/focus_thief"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
```

Then if this "thief" is placed at the top of the layout (to be first focusable item) calls to `clearFocus()` will work.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It is not required to add a separate "focus_thief" view if you have any other view in your layout that will take the android:focusable="true" &     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"parameters.  Just add those to the view above (if you have one) instead.

Answer (score 33):

You can also include **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"** in your manifest action section.

This is equivalent to :

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

but in XML way.

FYI, you can also hide the keyboard with codes:

```
// hide virtual keyboard
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mYourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I used only the part of the keyboard, thanks

Comment: And when you'll ineveitablly want to hide it, you'll have to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14327901/1166266

Answer (score 33):

To hide the keyboard when activity starts.. write the following code in onCreate()..

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

To clear focus and remove cursor from edittext.....

```
editText.clearFocus();

editText.setCursorVisible(false);
```

Comment: Note:  for ```editText.clearFocus();``` to work you need to add ```android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"``` to the root layout

Answer (score 29):

try to use this one on your view
it worked for me:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/fucused"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Comment: I can't believe how terrible is the focus management in Android, after trying different possible solutions until the point I was frustrated, this comment was the only option that works flawlessly... just adding a simple View on the xml does the trick (obviously you set the focus to that view when you want to remove from other) Thank you..

Comment: "fucused", exactly! :D

Comment: I’d say more like `Fuckused` but… yeah.

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me except this one. My SearchView was within a fragment and first view at the top of the view group hence it was taken focus no wonder what I try.

Answer (score 24):

Add to your parent layout where did you put your `EditText` this `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Comment: This trick works for me. In case the view is the first `EditText` it seems `clearFocus()` clears its focus but then starts searching for a focus candidate through the view tree and then finds out the same view. And the result is the same. But if you put `android:focusableInTouchMode` the focus traversal ends up on its parent.

Comment: this worked for me , thanks

Comment: so simple, so effective. thanks

Answer (score 21):

you have to remove `<requestFocus/>`

if you don't use it and still the same problem

user `LinearLayout` as a parent and set

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 11):

This is my very first answer on SO, so don't be too harsh on me if there are mistakes. :D

There are few answers floating around the SO, but I feel the urge to post my complete solution cause this drove me nuts. I've grabbed bits and pieces from all around so forgive me if I don't give respective credits to everyone... :)

(I'll simplify my result cause my view has too many elements and I don't wanna spam with that and will try to make it as generic as possible...)

For your layout you need a parent your *EditText* and *parent view* defined something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/lytContainer"
              android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:id="@+id/etEditor"
              android:inputType="number"
              android:layout_gravity="center" 
              android:hint="@string/enter_your_text"
              android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" 
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:textAlignment="center" 
              android:gravity="center" 
              android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, I needed a few things here. I needed to have a Placeholder for my EditText - which is that -

> android:hint="hint"

Also,

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

made it happen for *EditText* not to be focused on entering the *Activity* and later on in the *Activity* itself when setting it this setting helps so you can set *onTouchListener* on it to steal the focus away from *EditText*.

Now, in the Activity:

```
package com.at.keyboardhide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
private EditText getEditText;
private LinearLayout getLinearLayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.keyboardmain);
    getEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEditor);
    getLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lytContainer);
    getLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    getEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                Log.d("EDTA", "text was entered.");
                getEditText.clearFocus();
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(barcodeNo.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v==getLinearLayout){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        getEditText.clearFocus();
        return true;
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Few of the answers for bits I found on this question page, and the part with the Activity solution I found on this [blog](http://amitthaperandroidquery.blogspot.com/2011/10/remove-keyboard-after-click-outside.html?showComment=1395145892395#c3165564688676156529). The rest I missed which I had to figure out myself was clearing focus on the *EditText* which I added to both inside the *setOnEditorActionListener* and onTouchLister for the *parent view*.

Hope this helps someone and saves their time. :)

Cheers,
Z.

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"                                                                           Worked for me Thank you very much

Comment: @sharma_kunal Glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 6):

In the comments you asked if another view can be focused instead of the EditText. Yes it can. Use `.requestFocus()` method for the view you want to be focused at the beginning (in onCreate() method)

Also focusing other view will cut out some amount of code. (code for hiding the keyboard for example)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. It made me more than crazy.

I had an extended Dialog with a ScrollView that had a TableLayout with extended LinearLayout that contained a SeekBar and a EditText.

The first EditText had always autofocus after showing the Dialog and after finishing editing the text over the keyboard the EditText still had the focus and the keyboard was still visible.

I tried nearly all solutions of this thread and none worked for me.

So here my **simple solution**: (text = EditText)

```
text.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener( ){
    public boolean onEditorAction( TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event ){
        if( (event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) ||
            (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) ){
            text.clearFocus( );
            InputMethodManager iMgr = null;
            iMgr = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
            iMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow( text.getWindowToken(), 0 );
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

By the way I **didn't** used any of the following snippets to solve it:

```
//setFocusableInTouchMode( true )
//setFocusable( true )
//setDescendantFocusability( ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS )
```

AND I **didn't** used a spacer item like a View with width and height of 1dp.

Hopefully it helps someone :D

Comment: what is this? ^^  :) I will try all other solutions on StackOverFlow before trying this code.

Comment: This is a working solutions (for me) and I wanted to share it, because as I've written: "It made me more than crazy." Have fun by trying ALL other solutions, which are sometimes more complicated than mine by using wrappers or not needed functions and at the end they didn't worked for me.

Comment: It's fine if it worked for you, I solved it with `android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in the parent RelativeLayout.

Comment: This answer totally worked for me, removing focus of editText AND closing keyboard. I do have `android:focusable="true" `and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on parent layout though  Haven't tried without them, just happy that it works after two days shouting and trying everything under the sun. Stupid Android editText.

Answer (score 3):

You can also include `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` in your manifest action section.

This is equivalent to:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
```

The `EditText` will be able to get the focus when the user touch it.
When the main layout (activity, dialog, etc.) becomes visible the `EditText` doesn't automatically get the focus even though it is the first view in the layout.

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid any focus on your elements by setting the attribute **android:descendantFocusability** of the parent element.

Here is an example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/search__scroller"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ScrollView>
```

Here, the attribute android:descendantFocusability set to "blocksDescendants" is blocking the focus on the child elements.

You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setDescendantFocusability%28int%29).

Comment: You should use
`android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`
on the ScrollView's child

Comment: Thanks for alternate... :)

Answer (score -5):

```
check your xml file
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp" >

            **<requestFocus />**
 </EditText>


//Remove  **<requestFocus />** from xml
```