# Force Android's Softkeyboard in NumberPassword mode without EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way I can force show Android's SoftKeyboard in NumberPassword mode without having an actual EditText in my activity?

I managed to show the keyboard when the activity starts by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` on my AndroidManifest.xml, make it impossible to close by overriding `onKeyPreIme` in my `CustomView` class that extends `TextView`, and handling the touch events by myself by overriding `onKeyUp` in my Activity.

If I add `android:inputType="numberPassword"` directly in CustomView's XML Layout, Activity's onKeyUp gets bypassed and the keyboard write characters in my CustomView and KEYCODE_ENTER closes my keyboard.

What I want to achieve is:

- SoftKeyboard always out, both on Activity Start and Resume from the background
- Cannot be closed with KEYCODE_ENTER or KEYCODE_BACK
- 9-digit layout + Backspace
- Handle by myself key pressure to make it do something else instead of writing characters

Comment: Can you show some code to have a better picture of what you are doing?

Comment: Something very close to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591012/implementing-onkeypreimeint-keycode-keyevent-event-in-fragment/16108133#16108133 but without EditText. Numbers / Backspace will fire different methods based on the key pressed. That solution isn't working because, at least on my 6.0.1 Moto X, the KEYCODE_ENTER cause the keyboard to disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html for convenience:

> Both the `Activity` and `View` class implement the `KeyEvent.Callback`
>   interface, so you should generally override the callback methods in
>   your extension of these classes as appropriate.

I suggest you to override the default implementation of `onKeyUp` in your `CustomView` class, and make the `CustomView.onKeyUp` method redirect the event to your `Activity`'s `onKeyUp` method.

As an example:

```
public class CustomView extends TextView {
    private KeyEvent.Callback myKeyEventCallback;

    public void setCustomKeyEventCallback(KeyEvent.Callback callback) {
        myKeyEventCallback = callback;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return myKeyEventCallback.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity` do this:

```
CustomView view = ...; // here you take the reference to your custom view
view.setCustomKeyEventCallback(new KeyEvent.Callback() {
    // ... other methods

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // this calls your activity's implementation of onKeyUp
        MyActivity.this.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        return false; // prevent event from firing twice
    }
});
```

This will help you redirect the onKeyUp method calls from your `CustomView` to your `Activity`'s onKeyUp implementation.

Comment: With you solution I get the events fired twice, once by CustomView's onKeyUp and once by Activity's onKeyUp. I just set the callback's onKeyUp method to always return false, so I got event fired only once.