# Set Focus on EditText

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have an EditText-Field and set an OnFocusChangeListener for it. When it has lost focus, a method is called, which checks the value of the EditText with one in the database. If the return-value of the method is true, a toast is shown and the focus should get back on the EditText again. The focus should always get back on the EditText and the keyboard should show, until the return-value of the method is false.

EDIT: I think, I haven't made my real problem perfectly clear yet: No other Item on the Screen should be able to edit, until the value of the EditText is edited to a value, which makes the method "checkLiganame(liganame)" return false. Only the EditText-Field should be editable.

here is my code (which doesn't work for me):

```
final EditText Liganame = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.liganame);

    Liganame.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {

                String liganame = Liganame.getText().toString();


                if (checkLiganame(liganame)) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(CreateTableActivity.this,
                            "Dieser Liganame ist bereits vergeben",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    Liganame.requestFocus();
                }
            }
```

and the method:

```
public boolean checkLiganame(String liganame) {
    boolean found = false;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query("liga", new String[] { "liganame" },
            "liganame = '" + liganame + "'", null, null, null, null);
    Log.i("Liganame: ", String.valueOf(cursor));

    db.close();
    if (cursor != null) {
        found = true;
    }

    return found;
}
```

This code leads to the following result: After the EditText has lost focus, the focus jumps back to EditText, but I can't edit the text anymore.

EDIT2: Changed my code. Scenario:

I click on the first EditText and put a String in it, which is already in the database. The toast is showing. Now I can't edit my String anymore. I click "next" on the keyboard and the focus stays on the first EditText. I try to edit my String, but nothing happens. Instead my new String is showing in the second EditText. I click on the back-arrow of my device and reclick on the first and second EditText --> no keyboard is showing.

Here is my new Code:

```
public class CreateTableActivity extends Activity implements
    OnFocusChangeListener {

private EditText Liganame, Mannschaftsanzahl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_league);

    Liganame = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.liganame);
    Liganame.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    Mannschaftsanzahl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mannschaftsanzahl);
    Mannschaftsanzahl.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    final Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_tabelle_speichern_button);

    OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ButtonClick();
        }
    };
    save_button.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);



}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    String liganame = Liganame.getText().toString();

    if (checkLiganame(liganame)) {
        if (Liganame.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow()
                    .setSoftInputMode(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            Mannschaftsanzahl.clearFocus();
            Toast.makeText(CreateTableActivity.this,
                    "Dieser Liganame ist bereits vergeben",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the below answers are helped you, please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 373):

Just put this line on your `onCreate()`

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: It also automatically activates the opening of the virtual keyboard. So you don't need to do this in code.

Comment: it is not opening keyboard on my case.

Comment: Just add this lines below above code=>  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(_searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Answer (score 181):

Requesting focus isn't enough to show the keyboard.

To get focus and show the keyboard you would write something like this:

```
if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```

EDIT: Adding extra info to the answer after the checkLiganame method was added.

In the checkLiganame method you check if the cursor is null. The cursor will always return an object, so the check for null doesn't do anything. However the problem is in the line `db.close();`

When you close the database connection, the `Cursor` becomes invalid and most probably is nulled.

So close the database after you've fetched the value.

Instead of checking the cursor for null, you should check if the number of rows returned are more than 0: if(cursor.getCount() > 0) and then set your boolean to true if so.

EDIT2: So here's some code for how to make it work.
EDIT3: Sorry wrong code I added... ;S

First off, you need to clear focus if another `EditText` gets focus. This can be done with `myEditText.clearFocus()`. Then in your onFocusChangeListener you shouldn't really care if first `EditText` has focus or not, so the onFocusChangeListener could look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    private EditText editText1, editText2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        String liganame = editText1.getText().toString();

        if(liganame.length() == 0) {
            if(editText1.requestFocus()) {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                editText2.clearFocus();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dieser Liganame ist bereits vergeben", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace the first check `if(liganame.length() == 0)` with your own check, then it should work. 
Take note, that all the EditText views should have set their `onFocusChangeListener` to the same listener like I've done in the example.

Comment: Thank you so far. But this doesn't solve my whole problem. I edited the description of my problem.

Comment: So what is checkLiganame doing exactly? Why Can't you just check if(liganame.isEmpty()) and if it is true, requestFocus again?

Comment: Thank you :-) Now my method is working correctly :-) but my main problem with the EditText-Field isn't solved yet. I still can't edit it, after the method has found a row...

Comment: So you added if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
Inside the onFocusChanged listener?

Comment: Yes I did. Under Liganame.requestFocus();.
I click "next" on the keyboard, to jump in the next EditText-Field. The toast is showing and the focus is on BOTH EditText-Fields. But I can only edit the second one. The first one, which should be the only one having focus in this case, is not editable anymore.

Comment: I've tried your new code. But it doesn't work :-( I've put an edit in my original post.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? as I have the exact same problem with my project and posted my problem here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788512/how-to-force-focus-to-edit-text

Comment: Regarding the DB-related advice in this answer, [this blog post](http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474398246/android-sqlite-locking) shows why you're probably better off with a single global DB connection owned by your Application subclass. I make that connection and all accessors static for ease of use. You SHOULD close the cursor instance when you're done with it.

Comment: thanks for taking the effort. This is what makes SO awesome :)

Answer (score 71):

Darwind code didn't show the keyboard.

This works for me:

```
        _searchText.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(_searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

in case the keyboard is not showing, try to force:

```
        imm.showSoftInput(_searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Answer (score 25):

This works from me:

```
public void showKeyboard(final EditText ettext){
    ettext.requestFocus();
    ettext.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override public void run(){
                InputMethodManager keyboard=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(ettext,0);
            }
        }
        ,200);
}
```

To hide:

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText ettext){
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ettext.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to wait 200 ms? is it necessary or i can just show it immediately?

Answer (score 20):

This changes the focus of the EditText when the button is clicked:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText e1,e2;
    private Button b1,b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        e2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        e1.requestFocus();
        b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                e1.requestFocus();

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                e2.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This is what worked for me, sets focus and shows keyboard also

```
EditText userNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserNameText);
userNameText.setFocusable(true);
userNameText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
userNameText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(userNameText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Thanks. `setFocusable` requires API 26. Also `setFocusableInTouchMode` was not needed in my case.

Answer (score 8):

If we create an EditText dynamically then we have to set the requestFocus() as given below.

```
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setWidth(600);
    editText.requestFocus();
```

If already we declared the component in the xml view then we have to find it and we can the focus as given below.

```
EditText e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
e1.requestFocus();
```

It sets only focus to the corresponding EditText component.

Answer (score 6):

```
    mEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mEditText.requestFocus();

    if(mEditText.requestFocus()) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you try to call `requestFocus()` before layout is inflated, it will return false. This code runs after layout get inflated. You don't need 200 ms delay as mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944730/2760951).

```kotlin
editText.post(Runnable {
   if(editText.requestFocus()) {
       val imm = editText.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
       imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    Button btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    EditText editText1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            editText1.setText("");
            editText2.setText("");

            editText1.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61893375/12665616)

As I read on the official document, I think this is the best answer, just pass the View to parameter such as your EditText, but showSoftKeyboard seems like not working on landscape

```
private fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}

private fun closeSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

//Function Call
requestFocus(yourEditetxt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a single line:

```
yourEditText.RequestFocusFromTouch();
```

Comment: Actually this is the only answer that worked for me. It simulates the touch just as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin.Android I have created this extension.

```
public static class ViewExtensions
{
    public static void FocusEditText(this EditText editText, Activity activity)
    {
        if (editText.RequestFocus())
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            imm.ShowSoftInput(editText, ShowFlags.Implicit);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using `requestFocus()` in `onCreate()` introduces the issue of keyboard not showing on tap, use `BindingAdapter` using a [SingleLiveEvent](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) and request the focus inside that.

Here's how to do it:

**BindingAdapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("requestFocus")
fun bindRequestFocus(editText: EditText, event: Event<Boolean>?) {
    event?.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
        if (it) editText.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Dont know if you alredy found a solution, but for your editing problem after requesting focus again:

Have you tried to the call the method `selectAll()` or `setSelection(0)` (if is emtpy) on your edittext1?

Please let me know if this helps, so i will edit my answer to a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
new OnEditorActionListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      editText.requestFocus();
      //used ******* return true ******
      return **true**;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this code on manifest

```
<activity android:name=".EditTextActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
</activity>
```