# PlayN - Virtual keyboard on iOS and Android

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, playn

Is there a way to programmatically trigger the virtual keyboard on iOS and Android in PlayN?  Something like `Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(true);` in LibGDX.

The best I could find is the [Keyboard interface](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/playn/core/Keyboard.html), but from what I can tell, this can only get a whole line from the user, but I need per character (keypress) feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As for Android, I think you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext) answer. It does not give complete answer to it's question, but really fits yours.

To make long story short, you should have an EditText or some other control, able to receive keyboard input, request focus on it and in `onFocus`handler call `setSoftInputMethod`.