# I have an error in a thread making time "run" (update every second)

Tags: java, android, handler, ui-thread

Here is my code:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
```

The `Thread` is called `Thread` and I want to display the time in a `TextView` called `TextView`. There is some error in the `Thread`because even though the time displays in the `TextView`, it does not update every second. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging? The question, as it is, is very hard to answer.

Comment: use `Handler` instead

Comment: @NejsemNikdo Check this answer about the use of Handler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640896/3965050

Comment: @f1sh, I think that the problem is with "updating textview" in line 8 (`public void run() { //here

                        }`. But I am not sure with this and besides I don't know how to "update the textview"

Answer (score 2):

As stated, you should use `Handler` with `Runnable`, here is an example with your code:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Your code
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(task, 1000);
```

More info about Handlers, [in the doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: It shows an error "Variable 'task' might not have been initialized" on `task` in  the first `handler.postDelayed(task, 1000)` (under my code)

Comment: Thanks, now it does not show the error, but the clock in my app is still not running :(

Comment: @NejsemNikdo Can you please update your full code in the question? please, make it full, because that should work.

Answer (score 2):

use [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) And [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        textView.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm", time));

        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

---

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Check that he starts sleeping the thread, so the first post should be delayed as well.

Comment: I think he do that to make the task execute every second , not that he want to make it delay

Comment: Yes, of course, but he could put the sleep after the execution of his code, putting it at the begining is just to delay the first execution as well (maybe he is putting some data in the TextView already?, who knows...). But then again, maybe it is just a mistake. Just an observation.