# Edit text isn't being focused on

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was testing my app that has an edit text on my phone and worked fine. However, once I connected to another device which is running android 5.1 I believe, the app is not letting me type anything on the edit text. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try putting this in your onCreate

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext) for more answers

Comment: did you put after initializing your editText? also replace "editText" with the name of your edit text..

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that you have a reasonable value in your Manifest for the activity [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft). For instance try `stateVisible`.