# how to get focus when checked chekbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext

I have set setFocusable(false) in my edit text. But when i checked checkbox i want to get focus in my edittext. below is example.

```
cbIsGap.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {

                edittext1.setFocusable(true);
                edittext1.setClickable(true);

            }else {


                edittext1.setFocusable(false);
                edittext1.setClickable(false);

            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying above example but i am not getting focus when i checked checkbox

Comment: edittext1.requestFocus()  will provide focus to that editext

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext
  read here for more detail