# How to retain cursor in EditText when runOnUiThread() on same fragment is called to refresh Recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-runonuithread

I have a fragment containing a RecyclerView and an EditText. When the RecyclerView is refreshed using runOnUiThread(), the cursor from edit text is lost.
How to retain cursor in EditText when runOnUiThread() is called, without chaging values in EditText.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Focus on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext)

Comment: I do not think that's a duplicate, because OP has `EditText` inside `RecyclerView`, which can be tedious to handle.

Comment: OP just has to get the instance of the EditText that needs focus. So with little bit of self work and this is a duplicate.

Comment: i have tried focus but that does not solve my problem. Whenever  the runOnUiThread() is called to refresh recyclerView the cursor from edit text is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try call `requestFocus()` on EditText instance.

Comment: that works. I used requestFocus() inside runOnUiThread() and it works now.
Thanks