# How to automatically focus on Plaintext after going to another activity

Tags: java, android, select, focus, plaintext

I have an empty activity with just the PlainText on it.
I want it so that after the user taps on the button that directs him to the empty activity it automatically selects/focuses on the PlainText bringing out the built-in android keyboard ready to get user's input.

I tried

```
        android:focusedByDefault="true"
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything after going to the empty activity.

Comment: Can you please share your whole xml file of that empty activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

on your empty activity's `onCreate()` method

[Set Focus on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext)
See here.

Note: Normally the general problem is "hot to remove auto focus" from EditText so it focuses automatically, so maybe you changed some attributes from your xml, please share your empty activity xml with us.

Comment: Thanks dude, this solved my issue + the keyboard shows:

        if(editText.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMstrong textode(true);
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.requestFocus();
```

on your empty activity's `onCreate()` method