# afterTextChanged() event callback of TextWatcher gets invoked even when the user does not tap on the EditText field

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

I have an `EditText` field in my application and have a `TextWatcher` associated with it. The `afterTextChanged()` event callback gets invoked even when the user does not tap on the `EditText` to edit it. I need to check if the user has edited the EditText or not and with the current code it always calls the `afterTextChanged()` method when I load the activity.

```
//TextWatcher
textwatcher_timestamp = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String updatedText = s.toString();
                Log.v(TAG, updatedText);

            }
        };

        //Edit Text
        timestampereadback_text.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher_timestamp);
```

Comment: Does soft keyboard appear when open that activity ?

Comment: have u checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz nope

Comment: @abdulwasey20 I just checked, the editText.requestFocus(); does not work in this case

Comment: @abdulwasey20 that is different question

Comment: And you're not programmatically setting the text anywhere?

Comment: @HenryTwist I am, when reload the activity, I am doing a setText on the EditText because I need to retrieve the value from my Rooms database and show it there on the EditText

Comment: So surely that's what's triggering the change?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yeah, that was what was triggering the change

Comment: So your question is how to differentiate in the listener between programmatic changes and user triggered ones?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yeah, is there a way to do it?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yeah, that does! Thank your :)