# How to keep cursor from going to editText field on activity start android

Tags: android, xml

I am having a problem with text edits. I suppressed the keyboard from poping up on activity start, but how do I keep the cursor from being on the first edit text? I want the cursor to appear only when the editText field is clicked and when the activity starts.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/stuff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/stufflabel"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stuffpic"
            android:hint="@string/name_str"
            android:maxLength="20"
             />
```

Comment: Create a dummy element and set focus to it at startup.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly search the forum for similar posts.

one post i found is - 
[Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus)

I hope you are looking for something similar !

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dummy EditText on inside layout of the XML file, so that the focus will get on that EditText and not on other EditText.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```