# Disable auto focus on previous EditText after current EditText is hidden

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two `EditTexts`. `EditText1` and `EditText2`

I also have a feature that hides `EditText2` depending on which option you choose.

The problem is that if you are focusing on `EditText2` and run `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on it then it automatically reverts focus back to `EditText1` which does other stuff.

How can I prevent any focus events and just keep everything the same?

I've tried

```
EditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
EditText2.setFocusable(true);
EditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
EditText2.setFocusable(false);
```

While they disable focus on `EditText2` As soon as `visibility` is set to gone, `EditText1` receives focus

Comment: try setting `focusableInTouchMode="false"` for the parent layout

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: Try to first visible the `EditText1` then gone the visibility of `EditText2`

Comment: you can try `EditText1.clearFocus();`

Comment: upload your complete code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem. [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Putting this right before my EditText

```
<LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"/>
```