# EditText weird focus behaviour

Tags: android, android-edittext

Alright,

When I have the focus on my EditText and the keyboard etc is showing. I click on my drawable at the end of the edittext (Cancel button). I recognize this event with an onTouchListener and hide the keyboard, clear focus, etc myself.

However, when I 'touch' the cancel button, it hides the keyboard but the focus stays on the edittext. Meaning the cursor is still showing, but not blinking. So when I click on the edittext again to get focus, it shows the option to copy/paste, etc like I'm long pressing the cursor and doesn't show the keyboard.

But when I 'press' the cancel button, it clears the focus, hides the keyboard and most importantly it hides the cursor resulting in completely removing the focus. Then when I click on the edittext again, it gets focus back and DOES show the keyboard.

What is this weird behavior and how do I make it that it always does the 'press' behavior.

my code:

```
searchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (event.getRawX() >= searchView.getRight() - searchView.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width()) {
                    hideKeyboard(v);
                    isSearching = false;
                    searchView.setText("");
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                    searchView.setFocusable(false);
                    searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    getView().requestFocus(); // parent has both focusables true
                    searchView.setFocusable(true);
                    searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    fetchArticles();

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Like you're seeing, I'm trying everything I can to always get the same behavior. However no luck so far. Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: why are you requesting focus when you don't want?

Comment: Are u sure that `getView()` in `getView().requestFocus()` returns parent view? Looks like you requesting focus for the same view instead of parent.

Comment: Yeah quite sure it refers to the Fragment.getView();. I've also tried it with other views.

Comment: Is the searchView your last focusable view in your XML? Because if it is you are facing an Android system problem. You see, you try to clear focus out of the view, but then it has no other View to focus on, thats why the cursor does not disappear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus

Comment: Ricardo, no it's not the last focusable item in my XML. I have multiple other views before and after that can be focused. But I've solved the issue by using a seperate view for the button instead of the build in drawable function of EditText.

Comment: Quick Learner -> Not at all my problem. Might want to read the question a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Try these in parent of that EditText or in views you want to touch:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

It will allow to completely transfer focus elsewhere from EditText

However, in case when your drawable is inside of your Edittext like here:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon"
```

the solution won't work until you make drawable as separate view in layout.

Comment: Maybe you are doing something different. I tested right now in my project. I have 2 Edittext inside RelativeLayout. When I write above lines in xml of this relative, then press on relative outside of these edittexts, focus goes away, keyboard and cursor hides.

Comment: Yes, that happens with me as well. However when I press my drawable on the end of my edittext. I need to manually cancel the edittext etc and then it doesn't work.

Comment: is this drawable part of edittext or it is separate view in layout?

Comment: Maybe your solution is make it seperate?

Comment: Worth a shot, I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Yeah making a imagebutton on top does give me the desired behavior. Weird I have to resort to such a solution instead of a (in my opinion) normal solution.

Comment: Ok nice, I'll edit answer to make it simpler to newcomers

Answer (score 0):

Oke so my current 'solution' is a suggested solution by @Dmitriy Pavlukhin.

Instead of using the drawableEnd from EditText itself, I created a separate view which has the same drawable and make sure to draw this on the same position. Now when I click this view, it clears the view as desired 100% of the time. The codebase is still the same from the question, however it is now implemented in a OnClick on the separated view.