# How to clear focus from edittext when the keyboard closes after click back button?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `AppBarLayout` and I hide when I touch `EditText`.

**SearchFragment.class**

```
 binding.searchEt.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            binding.appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true)
        } else {
            binding.appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)
        }
    }
```

But I can't show again `AppBarLayout` when keyboard closes. Because when keyboard closes `EditText` focus does not change.

**Xml**

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/searchEt"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/close_button"
     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ic_search"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:fontFamily="@font/catamaran_bold"
     android:hint="@string/search_hint"
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
     android:includeFontPadding="true"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:paddingStart="12dp"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:textAlignment="viewStart"
     android:textColor="#000"
     android:textDirection="locale"
     android:textSize="18dp"
     tools:text="alskjfdn" />
```

How can I clear focus when keyboard hide? Cursor still showing after keyboard hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity){
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
  if(view != null){
    view.clearFocus();
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the keyboard close listener, after close keyboard clear focus from editText

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```