# How to remove the edit text focus after Editing the text and autosave the text in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a requirement like when user click on edit text only  it should be in the editable mode other wise non editable mode. And after editing the text need to remove the cursor and the updated text should be visible to Edit text. Please share me any idea.

How I implemented is:
my edittext xml

```
    <EditText
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/namevalue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotobold"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colortextw"
                />
```

And My Java code

```java
nameval.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        nameval.setCursorVisible(true);
        nameval.setFocusable(true);
        nameval.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        nameval.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

But the problem is, the cursor is not moving from the edit text after editing and when I move to the next page and came back to the same page the updated edit text is not showing in the edit text

Comment: The default behaviour of Edittext is same as what you want. You don't need to do anything else other than to just include it in your layout.xml

Comment: Here the updated edit text is not showing in edit text . when I again came to that class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus this may help you

Comment: why not saving your ediitext value using `onSavedInstanceState` ?

Comment: What you mean by coming to the activity again? Are you restarting the app? Or from another activity?

Comment: It might be anything i may close the app or move to another activity. if any thing is editted it should be saved automatically and display

Comment: @Wini whenever the text changes i need to save it . It means I need to write the edittext watcher and save that string in onSavedInstance

Comment: If you are restarting the app, it would remove the text of the editText as the activity's onDestroy() is called which would destroy the activity. And if you have another activity in your app(which is on top of this activity in stack) and you press the back button of your device, you should be able to see the text in edittext. Kindly refer here for details on activity lifecycle - [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: @Wini I Stored the edit text value to shared prefernece when ever there the edit text is edited. And when I close or moving to next activity and came back I am getting from shared pref and setting to edit text

Comment: @LahariAreti are you now facing some problem?you got what you want?

Comment: @Wini I got what I want . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get much from your requirement, but if want to enable the EditText after clicking on it and the after writing something to it you want to cursor focus to next edit text then billow snippets code will help you.

Example :

```
public class DemoActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    EditText editTextName = findViewById(R.id.etx_name);
    EditText editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.etx_email);
    EditText editTextMobile = findViewById(R.id.etx_mob);


    editTextName.setFocusable(false);
    editTextName.setClickable(true);

    editTextEmail.setFocusable(false);
    editTextEmail.setClickable(true);


    editTextMobile.setFocusable(false);
    editTextMobile.setClickable(true);

    editTextName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editTextName.setClickable(true);
            editTextName.setEnabled(true);
            editTextName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


        }
    });
    editTextEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editTextEmail.setFocusable(true);
            editTextName.setFocusable(false);
            editTextName.setClickable(true);
        }
    });

    editTextName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editTextEmail.requestFocus();
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    });

    editTextEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    editTextEmail.setFocusable(false);
                    editTextEmail.setClickable(true);
                    editTextMobile.requestFocus();
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: after user completing editing the text it should lose the focus to edit text.

Comment: I have written the   nameval.setFocusable(false); on after edit textchanged listener. And now its working fine