# How to make a TextInputEditText unfocused by default in android?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputedittext

I have created a Registration form and I wish for no text field to gain focus automatically when the activity starts. I have tried to add to all of my text fields but it is not working.

```
android:focusedByDefault="false"
```

XML Output

[image]

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/bio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="3dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Bio"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage"
            android:minLines="3"
            android:transitionName="logo_username"
            android:focusedByDefault="false"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="3dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="10">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:transitionName="logo_username"
            android:focusedByDefault="false"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:transitionName="logo_button"
        android:focusedByDefault="true"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/how-to-stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the root layout.

```
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

or adding this code on your manifest inside the activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
```

Comment: Thank You Ayush....the addition in manifest worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In android, focus automatically sets to the first root element that has focusable property. The workaround is the enable focusable property to your container element and the page will focus it instead of the first input element, triggering the keyboard. You have to set `focusable=true` (type it as it is not available in option) and `focusableInTouchMode=true` to the immediate parent container.

[image: focus setting]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me but still thank you for the piece of information about auto focus