# Android default onfocus on autofocus and editview,How to remove that?

Tags: android, android-activity, onfocus, oncreate

In my application I have a autocomplete in first activity and some edittext in second activity.

When I run my code in emulator it works fine and I am not seeing any virtual keyboard on screen when program is excecuted.

But when I deploy it in device when the application loads, onfocus is directly on autocomplete and a keyboard pops out, and also when I navigate from first activity to second activity onfocus is on first edittext and keyboard pops out.

**I want to disable this onfocus on all the page.** how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

[Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me... I just put this line in the activity definition on Manifest.

```
 <activity
                ...
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
 </activity>
```