# editText is not losing focus

Tags: android, android-edittext

the editText is not losing focus in my app when I click out of it, it has the orange border all time and that black line cursor..
I did this a LinearLayout according to this surrounding the editText:
[Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)
so it doesn't get focus on start of the app..

this is my code:

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
   INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

et.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   }
});

et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasfocus) {
      if(hasfocus) {
         imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
      } else {
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
   }
});
```

But, it doesn't seem to be calling the onFocusChange when I click anywhere outside the editText!

Comment: I am experiencing pretty much the same thing.  As far as I can tell, onFocusChange() is NOT generated when the focus is moved from one EditText to another via a touch event.  Perhaps @Overriding onTouch() might work?  Don't know off-hand.

Comment: Problematic this is. Now we have to modify code of `World\{EditText}`to get the one edittext to work. what the hell...

Answer (score 16):

It's simple. You can put the following in LinearLayout or any other else:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I used this in RelitiveLayout so that no EditText has focus all the time. +1

Answer (score 6):

Override `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null && view instanceof EditText) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            view.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
            int rawX = (int)ev.getRawX();
            int rawY = (int)ev.getRawY();
            if (!r.contains(rawX, rawY)) {
                view.clearFocus();
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

That way, whenever someone clicks anywhere, you have control, and it's at only one point in code.

Comment: Necessary add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`in a root layout

Answer (score 3):

Create an `onClick` listener, possibly in your XML layout to listen for clicks in the background LinearLayout.  From here you can call `.clearFocus()` on your `EditText` after you make it an instance variable of the activity you are working in.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the focus from the EditText, by setting the focus to other field by calling the method.

Suppose I have set the focus to back button on click of done button, then call the method on back button inside done button click listener.

And your problem is solved.

```
back.requestFocusFromTouch();
```