# Force focus on EditText if it loses focus

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want an EditText to always have focus no matter what so I subclassed EditText and added this:

```
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus) {
                requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

But the code does not work. Any clue why?

Comment: What other views are in the same layout?

Comment: Can you share your requestFocus() ?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489439/edittext-is-not-losing-focus?rq=1 - authot of this post is on opposite side, it may help