# Android: select all text on focus on EditField

Tags: android, text, edit

I'm trying to get Android to select all the text in an EditText field when it gets the focus. I'm using this attribute in the layout (on both fields):

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but to get the cursor to the first editable field (there's also a disabled field before it), I'm using the following commands:

```
quizStartNum.setFocusable(true);
quizStartNum.requestFocus();
```

But, while the cursor does move to the desired field when the layout is first displayed, the text doesn't get highlighted;  instead the cursor ends up to the left of the text, the default behavior. If I move to the second field by touching it, all the text is selected as desired. Then, if I move back to the first field, again by touching it, the text is also completely selected. I would like to have the behavior right from the start. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I just encountered similar problem. Moreover, I can't show soft keyboard for this EditText using `InputMethodManager#showSoftInput(View, int)` while `InputMethodManager#toggleSoftInputFromWindow(IBinder, int, int)` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

If `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` does not work, try calling `setSelectAllOnFocus(true)` on that particular EditText.

If that doesn't work either, this is another workaround from a previous SO post.

```
EditText dummy = ... 

dummy.setOnFocusChangedListener(new OnFocusChangedListener(){
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
        if (hasFocus) && (isDummyText())
            ((EditText)v).selectAll();
    }
});
```

Comment: No luck. android:selectAllOnFocus="true" does not work, setSelectAllOnFocus(true) doesn't work, and the above workaround doesn't work. Here's the code I used to get it to compile:  quizStartNum.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
  
          if (v.hasFocus()) 
          {
              ((EditText)v).selectAll();
          }
      }
  });

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` did not work for me.
The reason was that i was programatically requesting focus to the EditText before it was displayed. So if you are doing this for a EditText in an AlertDialog make sure you show it before you request focus to the EditText.

Answer (score 1):

EditText should be focussed after it displayed.

Following workout worked for me,

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Set Input Methode
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Dialog dialog = getDialog();
            if (dialog != null) {
            // Set Layout 
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            // Set Cancelable False
            setCancelable(false);

            // Set Focus Here <------------------------
            uiET_myTextView.requestFocus();
            }            
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your focus commands. They aren't necessary, Android should focus on the first field automatically?

Comment: He wants the second field to be focused as default.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that with android:selectAllOnFocus="true"  seemed not to work, I used the mouse to select EditText in the emulator, but if I used my finger and touched it, as if on the phone, it worked. If you don't have a touch screen on your computer you may have to install your app on a physical device to test it.
Android Studio may not recognize the mouse in this case

Answer (score -1):

I'll refer to [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus).

If you just want your `EditText` to show a hint (for "what goes in here"), you might want to use the Android's XML-attribute `hint` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint)).