# how to automatically make a text highlighted in android

Tags: android

in my android application the user can send feedback

```
public void c_send_send(View v) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:xx@xx.net");
    Intent send = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    send.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "feedback");
    send.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            DeviceInformation(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_version)));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(send, "feedback"));
}
public static String DeviceInformation(String app_name, String app_version) {
    String  EnterTextHere = "[Enter Text Here]"; 
    Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(EnterTextHere);
    spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 1, 17, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    String info = "\n" + spanText + "\n\n\n\nDevice Model: "
            + android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER
            + " " + android.os.Build.MODEL + "\nAndroid Version: "
            + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "\nApplication Version: "
            + app_version;
    return info;
}
```

the question how can i make

[Enter Your Text Here]

highlighted as shown in the picture posted in the link below

[Example](https://db.tt/4q3fZXpY)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Comment: hey guys please anyone recheck my question i make an edit but there is no change. any help here????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128297/how-to-dyamically-select-text-from-edittext-onclicklistener this will select your text from a certain index to another index

Answer (score 1):

Spannable strings are a very good way to use different styling in a single string. try exploring its different functions.

Comment: i'm stuck with spannable strings
it's done with text view but in my situation i don't know how to do it will you help me just to begin with it

Comment: there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus) option available, but it selects all the text, but you do not want that. So its better if you use the hint and send all the information in the background. That is because if you select some text, then the selection menu (cut-copy-paste) above will be shown, and you would not want that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it highlighted by the Toast option in android

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String)data.result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```