# dynamically select separated text in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an custom `Edittext` that is extended from `AppCompatEditText` and It shows date text like `"10.02.2012 10:40"` When user clicks **one time** over any part of texts, the part should be selected automatically.

For example:

[image]
  [image]

To do it, in my custom edittext, I overrode `onSelectonChange`

```
@Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {

        if (isFocused() && isCursorVisible() && isPressed()) {
            int[] aFoo = findPartOfText(selStart, selEnd);
            selStart = aFoo [0];
            selEnd = aFoo [1];
        }

        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

    }
```

It doesn't change anything. I have also tried this :

```
@Override
        protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
            //Select first 3 characters
            super.onSelectionChanged(0, 2);

        }
```

Result is same. It doesn't select the first 3 characters as well.

Comment: this can be achieved using an onClickListener or OnFocusChangedListener. here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128297/how-to-dynamically-select-text-from-edittext-onclicklistener)

Answer (score 0):

Try EditText.setSelection(int start, int end). when onSelectionChanged is called, check the cursor position or selection, and call setSelection to change it.

Comment: setSelection already calls onSelectionChanged method. So Calling setSelection method In onSelectionChanged  doens't make sense. Note: I have also tried your way before.

Comment: In onSelectionChanged, check the selection range. Only call setSelection if the range is not what you want.