# How do I select all text when clicking on a EditText view?

Tags: android

so I tried android:selectAllOnFocus and of course I'm using android:hint.
The app loads, requestFocus triggers and the full text is selected.

The problem is that when I click in the EditText the selection is lost.

I've already read:
[Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus)

Comment: That is perfectly normal. Otherwise, there is no way for the user to get rid of the selection.

Comment: Have you tried selectAllOnFocus through java code in an onclick event?

Comment: what do you expect *should* happen? by your logic, the selection will never go away once the user has clicked it. is this really what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the comments - the reason is the same as what you can see on the builtin android browser. Try going to a URL then click the URL bar, you'll find it automatically always selects the whole URL. The reason: having to delete it character by character would take too long.

Answer (score 9):

For some reason, it worked (on Jelly Bean) only if I posted it with a Handler:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        paidView.selectAll();
    }
});
```

Comment: same for my situation: calling setText() in a BroadcastReceiver in an EditTextPreference

Answer (score 1):

Set the selection in an `View.OnClickListener` like so:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setSelection(0, editText.getText().length() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, but this doesn't work. The text doesn't get selected. I do see what you are trying to do though, and I'm surprised it doesn't work either. I'm running ICS.

Comment: I don't think you need the ` - 1` part.

Answer (score 1):

Set the selection in an View.OnClickListener like so: (with the 0 and text length opposite to the previously approved response) - this will ensure that when the user starts typing the content will be overridden.

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - 1, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: To select all text you have to write editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length(), 0);

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but I had this same problem. For me, the reasoning was that I like to move the keyboard out of the way (dismiss it) to get my bearings (or hit buttons to add or remove rows of data) and when i touched back on the EditText I was previously editing, it was annoying to have the keyboard pop back up and the text un-select, forcing me to either work to get the cursor to where I wanted to start deleting, or touch another EditText and then touch back on the original to re-select everything. I just want to have the keyboard pop back up and have the text selected and ready to overwrite whenever I go to that EditText.

There are easy solutions to this:

1) Long tap does this for you on most occasions.

2) If you're already using `setSelectAllOnFocus(true)`, you can just throw a simple `clearFocus()` and `requestFocus()` in your onClick listener:

```
etMyEditText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
etMyEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.clearFocus();
        view.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

This way the EditText has everything selected when you tap on it, regardless of soft keyboard status.

Additional bonus: 
Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` inside your `<activity .../>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml file to force the selected EditText to stay in sight when the soft keyboard pops up.

Answer (score 1):

try This

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    editText.selectAll();
    //or this.selectAll();
}
```

To select all the text.

Answer (score 0):

Do the code below after you did `findViewById` and you are good to go:

```
    edtProductPrice.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
    edtProductPrice.requestFocus();
    edtProductPrice.selectAll();
```