# How to get all text selected on each click in my app

Tags: android

I am newbie to Android Development. I have created a helloandroidappwithlogin 
its completely working fine but just one thing where I am stuck is how to get the text selected

I have set the Username slot as Username So if a user tap/click on it, it should the username and start writing his username

to make things easy to understand i am attaching a screenshot

[image]

this is what I want to achieve

[image: when a user tap on username it should do like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus)

Comment: EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

int startSelection=et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=et.getSelectionEnd();

String selectedText = et.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection); try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `OnClickListener()` This is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856537/how-do-i-select-all-text-when-clicking-on-a-edittext-view) question.

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() - 1, 0);
    }
}
```