# Android EditText Select Text

Tags: android, select, android-edittext, onlongclicklistener

I have overridden the

```
OnLongClickListener
```

of the Android:EditText in order to show my own menu. However I would still like the user to be able to "select text" and "select all" from a button within my custom menu, how should I go about doing that?

EDIT: Sorry I should have put more detail in my question.

I have tried the selectAll() method for selecting the text however this doesn't come up with the two pointers (where the user can drag to select areas) which is what I mean by select text.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my question now

Answer (score 3):

Use findViewBy id to find that EditText when your custom button is pressed then use the following function:

```
((EditText)v).selectAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the **Related** column I found [Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus) which is easily adaptable to a context menu, you might find "select word" tactics there too.