# how to NOT select all on EditText long click

Tags: android, android-layout

When the user long-touches/long-clicks in the EditText, my app always selects all text. How do you instead make the EditText **not** select all, and instead select **only** the user-selected text?

I read [Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus?rq=1)
then tried explicitly setting `android:selectAllOnFocus="false"`but that is not working. Double tapping or any other click length doesn't work either.

To [override OnLongClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339765/android-edittext-select-text) might work, but I don't know how to get the user's start and end selected index.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128297/how-to-dyamically-select-text-from-edittext-onclicklistener

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181309/android-long-press-on-edit-text-behavior

Comment: "get the user's start and end selected index" from where? Who/what should supply you with these indexes?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try reading these liknks and see if they help:
[how to NOT select all on EditText long click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381087/how-to-not-select-all-on-edittext-long-click)

[how to NOT select all on EditText long click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381087/how-to-not-select-all-on-edittext-long-clickl)

```
You can try in your main.xml file:

android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Comment: How is this even an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are coming across this question in the future, the (or at least a) solution is to add the `textLongMessage` option to `android:inputType`:

```xml
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textLongMessage" >

<!-- Or you might have multiple input types -->
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" >
```

This will make the EditText's behavior be to select a single word from the text.