# Android EditText: select all text while touch and clear when user starts typing.

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edit text in my app. When the user touches the edit text the whole text should be selected and when he starts typing text should be cleared. An example is browser address bar. Is there any way to do this?Please help me.

Comment: would you please tell me, why you want to do this ?

Comment: Use the android:hint="text witch you want to display " after keyboard enable this is despra

Comment: You can do [this][1] to select all text inside edittext


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4669511/1627599

Comment: @Asfaq: I want to clear previous data when the user starts typing

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can select all text in EditText by using

[`android:selectAllOnFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aselectAllOnFocus) and also [`setSelectAllOnFocus(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelectAllOnFocus%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks.This selects the text but when  I again touch on the edit text to display the keypad, text is not cleared.

Answer (score 7):

Call `EditText.setSelectAllOnFocus(boolean selectAllOnFocus)` to select all text on focus.

Set a click listener to your `EditText` and in `onClick` call `edittext.selectAll();`

Comment: Set a click listener to your EditText and in onClick call edittext.selectAll();

Comment: Thanks, this is better than the answer, because you might not want your ET to have focus right away when you arrive in the activity. But instead of doing an `onClick` in the XML, I set an `onClickListener` in my ET activity, then put the `selectAll()` method to my ET on its `onClick()` method, and it selects all only when you click it.

Answer (score 3):

Add attribute to your main.xml file:

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Then all text will be selected and when user type something that will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property `android:hint` instead of `android:text` and you get what you want wihout special code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all text in EditText by using [`android:selectAllOnFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aselectAllOnFocus) or [`setSelectAllOnFocus(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelectAllOnFocus%28boolean%29).

Set a flag when all text is selected. Then detect a text change by using the [addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method on your EditText and make your class implement or define an inner class implementing the [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class.

In this watcher class method, check the flag you set to indicate whether all text is selected. if true, then do `TextView.setText("")`. This will clear the text. Now set the flag to false again so that subsequent text changes will not cause the text to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

This is working , all text will be selected and  when user type something that will remove it.

```
             editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);

            editText.requestFocus();
            editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) catalougeJobDetailFragment
                            .getActivity().getSystemService(
                                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    keyboard.showSoftInput(commentEt, 0);
                }
            }, 20);
```