# Selecting an Android EditView's text when it gets focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection

I have a view that contains a number of EditViews.  When one is selected, I want all of its text to be selected, rather than just having the edit cursor appear.  What I try is this:

```
EditText E = new EditText(this);
E.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
E.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
E.setText("Some Text");

E.setOnFocusChangeListener(
    new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                // Set the selection to the entire text
                EditText E2 = (EditText) v;
                E2.setSelection(0, E2.getText().length());
            }
        }
    }
);
```

When I select an EditText, onFocusChange is being called with hasFocus = true, but the text is not being selected; instead, the edit cursor appears as it usually does.

Also, when I include this line before the setSelection call:

```
E2.setText("Changed");
```

it sets the text to "Changed" successfully, but still doesn't select the text.

Also, if I use setSelected immediately after the initial E.setText call, the text in the EditText that has the initial focus is selected.

How do I select an EditView's text within an onFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange call?

Comment: try using this functiion : setSelectAllOnFocus (boolean selectAllOnFocus) check out this examples : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer @ItzikSamara ?

Comment: Sorry not for any obvious reason ..just came out like that really..

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by Itzik Samara ("use setSelectAllOnFocus(boolean)") in the comment to the original question - this was added so the question could be flagged as answered

Answer (score 0):

You can do three things here:

**If you prefer to do this programatically:**

1) You can call setSelectAllOnFocus(Boolean) *before* you call the OnFocusChangeListener(), eg:

```
E.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

2) Inside the hasFocus conditional, you can say

```
E.selectAll();
```

**If you would rather use your XML Layout :**

3) You can apply setSelectAllOnFocus on your EditText field in your layout, like:

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Hope that helps !