# Select all text when EditText has focus doesn"t work

Tags: android, android-edittext

When an EditText has a focus, I want to select all text inside by default, but it doesn't work:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                  // Go to the end
            editText.setSelection(getEditTextView().getText().length());

                    // Select all the content
                    editText.selectAll();
                }
            }
        });
```

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 good way to select the text in an EditText :

Inside your main.xml :

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Or :

```
editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
```

(If you want to do it programatically)

> SOURCE : [Select all text inside EditText when it gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669464/select-all-text-inside-edittext-when-it-gets-focus)