# Change what item has focus on startup. Remove focus from EditText

Tags: android, layout, view, android-edittext, focus

I have a `LinearLayout` and an associated `Activity`.  In my view there is an `EditText`'s box and a bunch of `Button`s.  When I start the application, focus goes immediately to the `EditText`s box and the soft keyboard comes up.  Is there a way to avoid this so that it just comes up with nothing selected and no soft keyboard popping up?  I have tried `findViewById().clearFocus()` and `requestFocus()` on different views, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Change your Activity settings in manifest like below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
</activity>
```

Comment: cool, that works, but the edit box is still selected.  I even try to findViewById(R.id.myedittext).setSelected(false) and it's *still* selected...

Comment: heh, I found answer, it's ...funny:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup