# TextInputLayout auto focus

Tags: android, android-design-library

I have a layout with a single `TextInputLayout` with an `EditText` inside it.

When the layout is loaded the `EditText` is immediately in edit mode, the keyboard is not up but the cursor is blinking and the hint is not inside the `EditText` but above it.

I want the hint to be animated out of the EditText only the the use first clicks the `EditText`.

How can I accomplish that? I have tried clearFocus() on both the `EditText` and the `TextInputLayout`.

My xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:id="@+id/case_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Case name" >
                </EditText>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: @Kuffs   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
does not work either, you are welcome to try.

Comment: Maybe the question I suggested was not a good example but there are many others asking the same thing. Please use the search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550429/edittext-android-automatic-focus  Check all answers not just the accepted ones.

Comment: This one has most activity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: @Kuffs this is not about the EditText, it's more about the TextInputLayout which is fairly new component with not a lot of reference.

Comment: The TextInputLayout is a wrapper around the EditText and is largely irrelevant. To achieve the effect you  asked for, you need to prevent focus on the EditText.

Comment: I've tried most of the suggestions there, they  on the best case scenario I was able to remove focus, but the EditText's hint was also removed

Comment: Add the `android:focusable="true`" and  `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` elements in the parent layout of EditText.

Comment: In case anyone (like me) is confused about how to interpret these pieces of advice, it does work to add

`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the immediate parent of the TextInputLayout (not the parent of the EditText).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false)
```

Comment: that hides the cursor, but the focus is still on the EditText, which means the hint is not displayed.

Comment: Could you show me your EditText?

Comment: Sure, i've edited the question

Comment: I think that the problem lies in the use of TextInputLayout. Is hint showing without TextInputLayout?

Comment: Yes, but above the EditText not inside it.

Comment: edit android:layout_height to wrap_content and remove layout_weight. Hint must be show

Comment: Since there's only one answer on this question, it's pretty unhelpful that it's not a correct one, and the correct answer is buried in the comments above.