# How to set the focus on button?

Tags: android

Hi I have some EditTexts and a button at the bottom of the view. Upon starting the activity, the first EditText will gain focus and a keyboard will pop up. I want to upon starting the activity, the focus will be on the button instead of the EditText and the keyboard should not pop up. I tried running:

```
button.requestFocus();
```

The EditText still have focus and pops up the keyboard. How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its trickier than it seems, but certainly possible. See here:

[Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: Thanks, been trying to figure that out for a few hours and couldn't do it. That link really save me.

Answer (score 2):

Put android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" to your Activity which contains EditText

```
    <activity android:name=".YourActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>
```

Comment: It worked well for me. Can you tell me which Android version of your project

Comment: I am using android 2.2 Thanks really appreciate it. The issue has been resolved by the workaround provided by yonester.

Answer (score 1):

You can force hide the keyboard by calling this on the EditText view

```
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Hope this helps,

-serkan

Comment: that did not work. focus is still on edittext and keyboard still pops up.