# button not getting focus

Tags: android

i am making an application with 4 buttons in it.I want to get them the focus whenever the mouse or some pointer moves over them.But i am not able to do that.Please tell me what is the problem. The coding of buttons is as follows.

```
            m_NextButton.requestFocus();
    m_PrevButton.requestFocus();
    m_SubmitButton.requestFocus();
    m_SkipButton.requestFocus();
```

The xml coding is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue"/> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue"  /> 
    <item  android:drawable="@drawable/button_lightgreen" />

</selector>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82825/how-i-can-improve-my-accept-rate-on-stack-overflow

Comment: what it does mean?Will you please explain

Comment: It means clicking on the V on the left side of the question that helped you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite tricky actually but not impossible. I did some digging in Google and found a similar question in Stack overflow:

[How to set the focus on button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605680/how-to-set-the-focus-on-button)

And it has a link leading here that helped the guy solve his problem : [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Answer (score 0):

No mouse in Android, no hoover in android like web...
The Galaxy Note can have hoover event, but by its 'stylus' only.