# Activity with EditText in layout, EditText is selected by default

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `Activity` with a simple layout, a kind of 'faux' web browser with an `EditText` for the URL input, defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/activity_title_bar">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/address" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:hint="@string/browser_hint_url"
        android:text="@string/browser_url">
    </EditText>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_refresh"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:src="@drawable/browser_button_refresh">
    </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="882sp" 
        android:layout_height="1532sp"
        android:src="@drawable/browser_background">     
    </ImageView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I am having is that when the `Activity` is started, be default the `EditText` is selected and the soft keyboard activated. I'd like for nothing to be selected to start, and thus not have the soft keyboard active, but can't figure out how to do this via XML.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: This is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup

Comment: Have you tried editText.setSelected(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=[         "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                       "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                       "stateAlwaysVisible",
                                       "adjustResize", ] >
```

Use some of this in your manifest, this will hide the automatic keyboard pop up. However, if you are using your EditText for some input at time you'll need the keyboard. :)

`stateHidden` will do the work

Comment: This was it, but also including the `android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` for the parent LinearLayout as per citizen conn's suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

get a reference to one of your other views, either the ImageButton, or the LinearLayout. Then in your onCreate() method call `view.requestFocus();` on the non-EditText view and it will steal focus away and keep the keyboard from being shown.