# Android issue with EditText object

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have an activity where the user is presented with a list of edit texts. The problem is, as soon as the activity starts, the virtual keyboard is brought up right away for the first edit text. I don't want this to happen as there is a spinner before this edit text, and often I've found that popping up the keyboard like this makes the user forget about that previous spinner.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/event_location"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30px"
    android:prompt="@string/location_prompt" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Event Name: " />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/event_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Activity Type: " />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/event_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address: " />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/event_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Summary: activity with an EditText starts, and the virtual keyboard automatically pops up. I don't want it to do this unless the user presses on the edit text.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EditText is automatically set to focus so you need to put `android:focusable="false"` or `editText.setFocusable(false)` to prevent the EditText to be focused while the spinner is visible. You could also try `editText.setSelected(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your spinner XML to this:

```
<Spinner 
android:layout_marginTop="30px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/event_location"
android:prompt="@string/location_prompt">
<requestFocus />
</Spinner>
```

Also try to do for each EditText:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Look at this post: [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: alright sure, I'll try that out. Is there a way I could just make it so that nothing has a prompt? I.e. nothing "pops up" until the user clicks on something.

EDIT - the requestFocus did not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works for me:

1. to make sure the edit text wont get focus on startup:
   In xml set the focusable attribute of the EditText to false:

```xml
android:focusable="false"
```

2. in order to make the *EditText* focusable again after startup:
 
set the focusable attribute from code in the `oncreate()` method  of the wanted activity after the `setContent()` method:

```java
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);
    ....

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_notes);

    et.setFocusable(true);

    et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    ...
}
```