# Change focus to a button while a listview is there, when loading the Activity

Tags: android, android-widget, focus, android-listview

Is it possible to give focus to a button when the activity starts, while a listView is there on the layout in Android? I tried the following code, but didn't work for me.

```
button1.requestFocus();
```

Further I tried

```
listview.clearFocus();
button1.requestFocus();
```

Still didn't work.. Can anyone see anything that I am doing wrong or is there a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried modifying `focusableInTouchMode` parameter? Similar problem is discussed here: [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

Comment: Hi teepee, Yes that was the problem. I added focusableInTouchMode="True" and now its fine. I had previously included focussable="True", Seems like that only not enough. Thank you verymuch...!