# android: get rid of focus when enter activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop EditText from gaining focus at Activity startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)

I have an activity has a EditText inside, and each time when the activity starts up, the EditText automatically get the focus.

I don't want the EditText gets the focus automatically, how can I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the similar issue and i am sure this is the problem, for that you just need to do a small trick.

Add this LinearLayout before the EditText which is getting focus at activity startup. You don't need to set any value inside the EditText.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0dip" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:id="@+id/dummyView"/>
```

Comment: not very clear, can you repeat more precisely? Thanks! Should I set anything to the EditText?

Comment: just above the EditText, add this LinearLayout, and you don't need to do any changes for EditText, FYI, we have added this layout as a dummy so that it will get focus while starting of activity.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in `<activity>` tag in your manifest for activity in which edittext is present.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

put `android:focusable="false"` may it will work for edittext

Comment: yes its working i tested it on my application

Comment: then how can you get focused when want to some edit in it?