# webview. keyboard automatically closes on forms

Tags: android, android-webview

I made a android webview app using the following code

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("*web url*");
```

the problem is that some forms in the webpage functions correctly but there are some forms that when I click on it, it automatically closes the keyboard therefore not allowing the user to type anything? any fix on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add requestFocus to your WebView like this:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Also try to alter windowSoftInputMode by reading the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft)

Comment: the solution didnt work. still closes the keyboard automatically

Comment: does the keyboard open again when you click in EditText or TextField though? @Reub

Comment: *also there is a navigation icon that doesnt work as well (hamburger icon).

Comment: Try to add onTouchListener to your webView :

`webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.requestFocusFromTouch();  
                break;
        }               
        return false;
    }

});` @Reub

Comment: I cant scroll down. i think something is missing?

Comment: does it respond to your clicks now though @Reub?

Comment: not yet. i cannot scroll down to the portion of the page that I need. seems the code keeps on scrolling the page up

Comment: have you tried loading different web page? @Reub, also make sure you have set the view orientation to vertical beforehand.

Comment: there is a form that works that redirects me to that page with another form where the error occurs. the previous page's form was working correctly

Comment: Very interesting, your first page works. Try to clear the cache and history as I assume your webView is still holding its reference to the first page? @Reub
`webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();` ,

Comment: still not working. any idea about the navigation (hamburger logo)? doesnt seem to work when I click on it.

Comment: do you know what this means? Autofill suggestions are disabled because the document isn't a secure context or the form's action attribute isn't secure. this seems to popup in the logcat every time I click on that form

Comment: Sorry for late reply, in my opinion it might have something to do with http or https protocol ?

Comment: looks like the problem is with the windows.resize as described here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854359/android-html-input-loses-focus-when-soft-keyboard-opens-asp-net

Comment: Looks like you have to tweak the web code doesn't it? It is solved now though? Good luck mate

Comment: yea we were able to fix it. just removed some part of the css. thanks btw. the only thing left to solve is the hamburger icon not working in webview.