# Inputs and textareas are hovered by soft keyboard

Tags: html, css

I have an input and few textareas, which are situated on fixed divs. In iOS when I touch them they jump with keyboard, so I can see them. But in Android, that doesn’t happen - keyboard just overlays them. I am talking about **the site, not an android/ios app**

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14854359/863110) question could help. It also will help if you would post an example and mention if it's happening in all android versions or below / above specific version..

Answer (score 1):

Stuff, where inputs are situated, fill the page size, so I replaced parent `top:0` with  `bottom:0`.

Now the whole container with inputs is jumping with keyboard apear, **but** now inputs which are situated higher than document half height jump over window top when keyboard apear.

Unfortunately, the single solution I made is check before keyboard apear if the input situated higher than half height then set container `bottom: auto` and `top: 0`. On `blur` all go back.

Now it works. Android is very cool platform, as you can see