# EditText not getting focus Mono Android

Tags: android, focus, xamarin.android, android-tabactivity, custom-titlebar

I'm using TabActivity with Custom Title.

`TabControl.xml` contains

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

---

When activity gets launched, default tab is Tab0.

in .xml of Tab0:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

---

while for custom title bar, `TitleBar.xml` contains:

```
<RelativeLayout
    //not setting android:focusable here >

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edsearch" 
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/edsearch" 
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/edsearch" >
```

---

But the problem is when I try to enter any input in `EditText` of `TitleBar`, it doesn't work. The reason behind this might be `EditText` is not having focus.

To rectify it, I used `:nextFocusUp` and `:nextFocusUp` as suggested **[In this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555109/stop-edittext-from-gaining-focus-at-activity-startup)**

But still it doesn't work.

I've used OnClick event for EditText which gets fired on click of it.

But TextChanged event is not getting executed as I'm not able to provide any input into EditText.

As I'm new to *Mono Android*, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
android:focusable="true"    
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

from the Tab activity.

No need to set

```
android:focusable="true"    
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"    
android:nextFocusUp="@id/edsearch"     
android:nextFocusLeft="@id/edsearch"
```